# Make Error 127 when running trying to compile code

Tags: gcc

This semester I got this new subject where we get to work with Discovery STM32 F4, and we are still in the phase of setting it up. But I have this problem in the beginning.

When I try to compile this "blink" code I get this error:

[image: Error 127]

So, as I got it so far, we are using this shortcut command "make" to compile code, and we were given instruction to set it up as it's shown in images below:

[image: Setup]]

Can anyone see what's the problem here?

Comment: It can't find/execute `arm-none-eabi-gcc` (presumably the gcc compiler for that device) at the specified location. Check if the executable is present and if the location is correct.

Comment: What does the following command return? gcc -v

Comment: Thank you for quick response. 
I've shown in second image ls of the directory where arm-none-eabi-gcc should be, and it's listed there.

Comment: And also, gcc -v returns: No such file or directory

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`Error 127` means one of two things:

1. file not found: the path you're using is incorrect.  double check that the program is actually in your `$PATH`, or in this case, the relative path is correct -- remember that the current working directory for a random terminal might not be the same for the IDE you're using.  it might be better to just use an absolute path instead.
2. ldso is not found: you're using a pre-compiled binary and it wants an interpreter that isn't on your system.  maybe you're using an x86_64 (64-bit) distro, but the prebuilt is for x86 (32-bit).  you can determine whether this is the answer by opening a terminal and attempting to execute it directly.  or by running `file -L` on `/bin/sh` (to get your default/native format) and on the compiler itself (to see what format it is).

if the problem is (2), then you can solve it in a few diff ways:

1. get a better binary.  talk to the vendor that gave you the toolchain and ask them for one that doesn't suck.
2. see if your distro can install the multilib set of files.  most x86_64 64-bit distros allow you to install x86 32-bit libraries in parallel.
3. build your own cross-compiler using something like [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/).
4. you could switch between an x86_64 & x86 install, but that seems a bit drastic ;).

Comment: Thank you, sir. You helped me a lot, so the problem was my Ubuntu was x64y and that was the whole problem. I changed back to x86 and it works just fine.

Thanks, one more time.

Comment: I've found a third situation to trigger this error and it should be edited into this answer when possible (edits queue is full).

3. One or many build executables do not have permission to run. Make sure you `chmod +x` any scripts or executables used in the make process.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved in a pull request (https://github.com/libopencm3/libopencm3/pull/1510)

Just add the code `MAKE := make` to the makefile of the `libopencm3/` directory