# build memtest86 (v4) from source code. make iso error

Tags: makefile

My knowledge on Linux is very poor, so don't go too hard on me, please.

I tried to create a bootable CD-ROM(ISO image) from memtest86's source code.

I followed the instruction in user manual, type "make iso", but I got the error message below:

=====================================

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/chris/src'
./makeiso.sh

make: ./makeiso.sh: Command not found

make: *** [iso] Error 127

=====================================

I have searched error 127, and I found this [Make, error 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365752/make-error-127)

I think my path is correct, so is binary a problem?

My system is 64 bits.

The source code can be downloaded here [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzf0YDyLesLjem4tMnhhbGFVS28)

Comment: The source code can be download here: [link](https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm)  MemTest86 V4.3.7 (OLD RELEASE)

Comment: The line above that shows the problem: the Makefile (which is preparing the iso) can't find the file makeiso.sh in the directory it expects it in. This may mean something went wrong further above causing it to not create the makeiso.sh file, or that there's a problem with the path, or that the set of files you downloaded have a bug, or that the download was incomplete...Poke around that folder and see if you can find the makeiso.sh file, at least to see if it exists.

Comment: You're right. The file makeiso.sh does not exist. Should it be created by compiling the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you want to compile it yourself? You may save some hassle by downloading the prebuilt .iso files. Aside from that, there's a lot of confusion going on here to the point that I'm not sure what's going on. There's memtest86 and memtest86+, which are two different products with a common origin. Some of the references I found to memtest86 are actually for [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/#downcode), which makes this all the more murky. There's also a [memtest86++](https://github.com/skottler/memtest86), which doesn't do much to make my head stop spinning.

[Memtest86](https://www.memtest86.com/download.htm) has a downloadable .iso image available which includes the source code, and at a quick glance it appears to be the source code you also have so I think this is the one you've got. The Makefile references `makeiso.sh`, but it isn't included in the source at all. I have no explanation for why this would be or how to resolve it. You might try copying the file from one of the other forked projects, but I couldn't guess whether that will actually work or if there are other files that might be missing as well. I'd suggest you contact their support for help.

Memtest86+ appears to have a much more [complete source code repository](https://github.com/Distrotech/memtest86); for example the `makeiso.sh` file is included here. If memtest86 isn't working for you, you may wish to consider memtest86+ (I have no idea of the differences between the two or merits of each; I'm just proposing an alternative since the first isn't compiling for you).

In summary, I think your best options are (1) contact support for help, (2) use the prebuilt .iso file instead of compiling yourself, or (3) try an alternative program.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have contacted them for help, but they don't offer free technical support for coding and compiling issues.