# Trouble compiling rust crates that include C libraries for aarch64

Tags: c, docker, rust, cross-compiling, arm64

I am trying to compile a rust app in an aarch64 linux docker container to run on raspberry pi 4. I have things working except when a package is not pure rust and utilizes c libraries. The [ring crate](https://crates.io/crates/ring) is an example of this, when I try to build the ring library without setting `ENV TARGET_CC=something` it fails with the following error:

```
#18 32.35    Compiling ring v0.16.19
#18 38.13 error: failed to run custom build command for `ring v0.16.19`
#18 38.13 
#18 38.13 Caused by:
#18 38.13   process didn't exit successfully: `/usr/src/content-manager/target/release/build/ring-902dd3bf18c6ec17/build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
#18 38.13   --- stdout
#18 38.13   OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
#18 38.13   TARGET = Some("aarch64-unknown-linux-musl")
#18 38.13   HOST = Some("aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu")
#18 38.13   CC_aarch64-unknown-linux-musl = None
#18 38.13   CC_aarch64_unknown_linux_musl = None
#18 38.13   TARGET_CC = Some("aarch64-linux-musl-gcc")
#18 38.13   CFLAGS_aarch64-unknown-linux-musl = None
#18 38.13   CFLAGS_aarch64_unknown_linux_musl = None
#18 38.13   TARGET_CFLAGS = None
#18 38.13   CFLAGS = None
#18 38.13   CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
#18 38.13   DEBUG = Some("false")
#18 38.13   CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = None
#18 38.13 
#18 38.13   --- stderr
#18 38.13   running "aarch64-linux-musl-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/aesv8-armx-linux64.o" "/usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.19/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S"
#18 38.13   thread 'main' panicked at 'execution failed', /usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.19/build.rs:673:9
#18 38.13   note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

In the ring [build docs](https://github.com/briansmith/ring/blob/main/BUILDING.md) it mentions the need to set TARGET_CC and TARGET_AR, when I set TARGET_CC to aarch64-Linux-gnu-gcc I get the following error

```
#18 62.62   process didn't exit successfully: `/usr/src/content-manager/target/release/build/ring-902dd3bf18c6ec17/build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
#18 62.62   --- stdout
#18 62.62   OPT_LEVEL = Some("3")
#18 62.62   TARGET = Some("aarch64-unknown-linux-musl")
#18 62.62   HOST = Some("aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu")
#18 62.62   CC_aarch64-unknown-linux-musl = None
#18 62.62   CC_aarch64_unknown_linux_musl = None
...
#18 62.62   CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
#18 62.62   DEBUG = Some("false")
#18 62.62   CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = None
#18 62.62   running: "aarch64-linux-musl-ar" "cq" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/libring-core.a" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/aesv8-armx-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/ghashv8-armx-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/vpaes-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/armv8-mont-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/chacha-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/ecp_nistz256-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/ghash-neon-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/sha512-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/sha256-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/aes_nohw.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/montgomery.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/montgomery_inv.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/limbs.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/mem.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/poly1305.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/crypto.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/curve25519.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/ecp_nistz.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/ecp_nistz256.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/gfp_p256.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/gfp_p384.o"
#18 62.62   exit code: 127
#18 62.62 
#18 62.62   --- stderr
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/aesv8-armx-linux64.o" "/usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.19/pregenerated/aesv8-armx-linux64.S"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/ghashv8-armx-linux64.o" "/usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.19/pregenerated/ghashv8-armx-linux64.S"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/vpaes-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.19/pregenerated/vpaes-armv8-linux64.S"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/armv8-mont-linux64.o" "/usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.19/pregenerated/armv8-mont-linux64.S"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/chacha-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.19/pregenerated/chacha-armv8-linux64.S"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/ecp_nistz256-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.19/pregenerated/ecp_nistz256-armv8-linux64.S"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/ghash-neon-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.19/pregenerated/ghash-neon-armv8-linux64.S"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/sha512-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.19/pregenerated/sha512-armv8-linux64.S"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/sha256-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/local/cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ring-0.16.19/pregenerated/sha256-armv8-linux64.S"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c1x" "-Wbad-function-cast" "-Wnested-externs" "-Wstrict-prototypes" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/aes_nohw.o" "crypto/fipsmodule/aes/aes_nohw.c"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c1x" "-Wbad-function-cast" "-Wnested-externs" "-Wstrict-prototypes" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/montgomery.o" "crypto/fipsmodule/bn/montgomery.c"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c1x" "-Wbad-function-cast" "-Wnested-externs" "-Wstrict-prototypes" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/montgomery_inv.o" "crypto/fipsmodule/bn/montgomery_inv.c"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c1x" "-Wbad-function-cast" "-Wnested-externs" "-Wstrict-prototypes" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/limbs.o" "crypto/limbs/limbs.c"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c1x" "-Wbad-function-cast" "-Wnested-externs" "-Wstrict-prototypes" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/mem.o" "crypto/mem.c"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c1x" "-Wbad-function-cast" "-Wnested-externs" "-Wstrict-prototypes" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/poly1305.o" "crypto/poly1305/poly1305.c"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c1x" "-Wbad-function-cast" "-Wnested-externs" "-Wstrict-prototypes" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/crypto.o" "crypto/crypto.c"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c1x" "-Wbad-function-cast" "-Wnested-externs" "-Wstrict-prototypes" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/curve25519.o" "crypto/curve25519/curve25519.c"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c1x" "-Wbad-function-cast" "-Wnested-externs" "-Wstrict-prototypes" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/ecp_nistz.o" "crypto/fipsmodule/ec/ecp_nistz.c"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c1x" "-Wbad-function-cast" "-Wnested-externs" "-Wstrict-prototypes" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/ecp_nistz256.o" "crypto/fipsmodule/ec/ecp_nistz256.c"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c1x" "-Wbad-function-cast" "-Wnested-externs" "-Wstrict-prototypes" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/gfp_p256.o" "crypto/fipsmodule/ec/gfp_p256.c"
#18 62.62   running "aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-I" "include" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c1x" "-Wbad-function-cast" "-Wnested-externs" "-Wstrict-prototypes" "-pedantic" "-pedantic-errors" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-Wcast-align" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wconversion" "-Wenum-compare" "-Wfloat-equal" "-Wformat=2" "-Winline" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wmissing-field-initializers" "-Wmissing-include-dirs" "-Wredundant-decls" "-Wshadow" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wsign-conversion" "-Wundef" "-Wuninitialized" "-Wwrite-strings" "-fno-strict-aliasing" "-fvisibility=hidden" "-fstack-protector" "-g3" "-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE" "-DNDEBUG" "-c" "-o/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/gfp_p384.o" "crypto/fipsmodule/ec/gfp_p384.c"
#18 62.62 
#18 62.62 
#18 62.62   error occurred: Command "aarch64-linux-musl-ar" "cq" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/libring-core.a" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/aesv8-armx-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/ghashv8-armx-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/vpaes-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/armv8-mont-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/chacha-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/ecp_nistz256-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/ghash-neon-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/sha512-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/sha256-armv8-linux64.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/aes_nohw.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/montgomery.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/montgomery_inv.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/limbs.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/mem.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/poly1305.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/crypto.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/curve25519.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/ecp_nistz.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/ecp_nistz256.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/gfp_p256.o" "/usr/src/content-manager/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/release/build/ring-ce2ec03868462ce3/out/gfp_p384.o" with args "aarch64-linux-musl-ar" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 127).
#18 62.62 
#18 62.62
```

I'm not very knowledgeable about all the flavors of C compilers out there and what combination I need to get this working but it seems like (hopefully) I just need a small config or environment variable change to be able to compile all the packages I need on aarch64. Hoping someone can point me to some relevant documentation or provide me with an example or answer for what environment variables need to be set to what value to get this working.

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "app"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Marcus Ruddick"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
ring = "0.16.19"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM rust as builder
ARG APP_NAME="app"
ARG TARGET="aarch64-unknown-linux-musl"
ARG GITHUB_SSH_KEY=""
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu -y
RUN rustup target add $TARGET;
RUN mkdir /usr/src/$APP_NAME
WORKDIR /usr/src/$APP_NAME

ENV CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI=true
ENV TARGET_CC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc

COPY Cargo.toml Cargo.lock ./
COPY ./src ./src

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN echo "$GITHUB_SSH_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa;
RUN chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts

RUN cargo build --release --target=$TARGET
RUN groupadd -g 10001 -r $APP_NAME
RUN useradd -r -g $APP_NAME -u 10001 $APP_NAME

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

FROM scratch
ARG APP_NAME="app"
ARG TARGET="aarch64-unknown-linux-musl"
WORKDIR /user/local/bin/
COPY --from=0 /etc/passwd /etc/passwd
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/$APP_NAME/target/$TARGET/release/$APP_NAME ./app
USER $APP_NAME

CMD ["./app"]
```

Build command

```
$ docker buildx build --load --platform=linux/arm64 -t myrepo/mytag:arm-0.0.1 .
```

Comment: Quick question: Why do you compile for `aarch64-unknown-linux-musl` instead of `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu`? That works fine for me on aarch64 and according to https://github.com/briansmith/ring/issues/713 there might still be some problems compiling for the musl libc.

Comment: @HHK Compiling for `aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu` doesn't work when attempting to run the binary from the scratch container, I need a statically linked binary like what is produced by musl otherwise if I try to run the container I get the following error

```standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: no such file or directory```

since the dynamically linked libraries don't exist in the scratch container

Comment: Can you run `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` ? On the gcc side you have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365752/make-error-127-when-running-trying-to-compile-code/36368057). Did you try [rebooting](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=240388)?

Comment: Please add a proper backtrace as we can only guess from this.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get it working after copying the env vars in [this file](https://github.com/briansmith/ring/blob/main/mk/cargo.sh) mentioned [here](https://github.com/briansmith/ring/issues/713#issuecomment-744649960)

My updated Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM rust as builder
ARG APP_NAME="app"
ARG TARGET="aarch64-unknown-linux-musl"
ARG GITHUB_SSH_KEY=""
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install clang llvm -y
RUN rustup target add $TARGET
RUN mkdir /usr/src/$APP_NAME
WORKDIR /usr/src/$APP_NAME

ENV CARGO_NET_GIT_FETCH_WITH_CLI=true

ENV CC_aarch64_unknown_linux_musl=clang
ENV AR_aarch64_unknown_linux_musl=llvm-ar
ENV CARGO_TARGET_AARCH64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_MUSL_RUSTFLAGS="-Clink-self-contained=yes -Clinker=rust-lld"
ENV CARGO_TARGET_AARCH64_UNKNOWN_LINUX_MUSL_RUNNER="qemu-aarch64 -L /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu"

COPY Cargo.toml Cargo.lock ./
COPY ./src ./src

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN echo "$GITHUB_SSH_KEY" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa;
RUN chmod 400 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts

RUN cargo build --release --target=$TARGET
RUN groupadd -g 10001 -r $APP_NAME
RUN useradd -r -g $APP_NAME -u 10001 $APP_NAME

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

FROM scratch
ARG APP_NAME="app"
ARG TARGET="aarch64-unknown-linux-musl"
WORKDIR /user/local/bin/
COPY --from=0 /etc/passwd /etc/passwd
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/$APP_NAME/target/$TARGET/release/$APP_NAME ./app
USER $APP_NAME

CMD ["./app"]
```

With this set up the binary compiles and runs from the scratch container, thanks @HHK for pointing me to the open issues on this topic

Answer (score 0):

I solved the "failed to run custom build command for ring" issue using [rust-musl-builder](https://github.com/emk/rust-musl-builder).

Here is what I did:

1. Add the target to rust toolchain:

```sh
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-musl
```

2. Define alias to run a docker container

```sh
alias rust-musl-builder='docker run --rm -it -v "$(pwd)":/home/rust/src ekidd/rust-musl-builder'
```

3. Build your project using the container

```sh
rust-musl-builder cargo build --release
```

Here is a list of supported targets: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/platform-support.html