# Is there any way to tell make to print better diagnostic information when a failure occurs?

Tags: cygwin, gnu-make

GNU make is generating errors whose root cause is eluding me.

Some brief background: The project is an embedded firmware. We are cross-compiling on a windows host. The build actually runs in the cygwin environment. I have been building the project for some time without any problems. This is a key point. The project was building OK and I have made no changes to the project source or the Makefiles.

A few days ago I installed python3 on my cygwin environment. It had been a while since I ran the Cygwin setup and the setup recommended I update a dozen or so other packages. I accepted the update suggestions without much thought. I did not capture the list of packages or the old versions. I mean, what could go wrong?

Here's what went wrong: the next time I built this project, make failed. The error is cryptic and the root cause is eluding me. I downgraded GNU make from 4.3-1 (the new version) back to 4.2.1-2, but the project still does not build properly.

Here is the error:

```
$ make -j8
compile message for file1.c
compile message for file2.c
...
compile message for fileN.c
make: *** [../../build/rules.mak:407: ../obj/fileN.o] Error 127
```

Error 127 is not listed here in the docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html

Searching for Error 127, I found this issue on SO: [Make Error 127 when running trying to compile code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365752/make-error-127-when-running-trying-to-compile-code). On the surface the issues look similar and the answer helped me dig into the problem. The root cause identified in that answer was the execution of a command that mismatches the host architecture. But (1) I do not think the root cause is the same -- see details below, and (2) if the root cause is the same, none of the suggested solutions are viable options for this project.

Here is why I say the root cause is elusive:

1. If I run `make -j8` again, make will build fileN.c without issue, but fail later on file X. I can repeat this process several times until everything builds, but that is not a valid answer, neither for a human or for an automated build.
2. If I run `make clean` and then start over again, make will fail with different files, e.g. file N will build OK but make will fail on file M or P.
3. If I run `make -j1` with only one job, the build usually succeeds without errors, but not always.
4. The line number called out by make -- initially -- was a make macro with several commands, so it wasn't clear which command might be the problem. So I added some diagnostics to the recipe: `which dos2unix`, `file -L dos2unix`, `dos2unix --version`, those sorts of things. Now, with those diagnostics added, when make fails, it sometimes generates the 127 error on a line with a simple command like `echo "dos2unix version:"`. How can `echo` cause an error 127? And why not the previous two-dozen times this exact same echo command was executed?

I want to draw attention to this last point, because make is not providing any useful diagnostic information here at all.

It's pretty clear that the error is not the execution of a command that mismatches the host architecture. Make executes the same commands over and over without errors.

It's pretty clear the issue is not about any particular source file, because re-running make produces a different success/fail profile.

Here is one example of a recipe that fails. Keep in mind that the same recipe succeeds many dozens of times before failing. And if I `make clean`/`make`, the failure occurs when processing difference source files.

```
357 define GENERATE_DEPENDENCY
358   @dos2unix -q $(@:.o=.d)
359   @sed -e '/[a-zA-Z]:/ {' \
360       -e 's/\([a-zA-Z]\):[\\\/]/\/cygdrive\/\L\1\//g' \
361       -e 's/\(.\)\\\(.\)/\1\/\2/g' \
362       -e '}' < $(@:.o=.d)  > $(@:.o=.dep)
363   @cp $(@:.o=.dep) $(@:.o=.dp2)
364   @sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
365       -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < $(@:.o=.dp2) >> $(@:.o=.d)
366   @rm $(@:.o=.dp2)
367
368 endef
...
404 $(COBJS) : $(OBJOUTPUTDIR)/%.o : %.c $(EVERYTHING_DEPENDS_ON) | $(OBJOUTPUTDIR)
405     $(COMPILEHOOK)
406     $(CC) $(LISTINGFLAG)=$(@:.o=.lst)  -c $(CPPINC) $(CPPFLAGS)  -MD $(call fixpath,$<) -o $@
407     $(GENERATE_DEPENDENCY)
```

It doesn't seem like the problem is in the project at all. I have gone so far as to delete the project and pull a fresh copy of the project that built correctly before my cygwin upgrade. But that did not solve the problem.

I wish I could go back to the earlier install of cygwin, but I have no backup. I don't even know which packages were upgraded.

Is there any command-line option that will tell make to print better diagnostic information for a failure, I would appreciate the information. I tried the "all debug info" option:

```
$ make -j8 -d > make-output 2>&1
```

Make generated 4.8MB (86K lines) of output and the build succeeded. But this is about as slow as building with one job, which is highly undesireable. Using `make -d` would also complicate locating real build issues when they happen.

Alternately, if the root cause somehow really is an architecture mismatch, is there some way to get make to identify the command it was trying to execute when the error occurred? As it stands now, I do not know which command might be causing the problem, or if indeed the problem really is an architecture mismatch.

Comment: if you are running `make -j8` you can see message of the several istance overlapping. It is possible that the error is not coming from `echo`. What tools are you using in the build ? All python3.x assign `python` to the highest `python3.x` installed by default. https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2021-May/010038.html

Comment: I installed python for a different project. Python isn't used to build this project -- the python installation was just the catalyst for the cygwin upgrade. The reason I am pointing to `echo` is because make is pointing to `echo`. I added my own diagnostic commands to isolate the root cause of the failure. I also added echo commands to clarify the diagnostics output. That's when make started reporting "Error 127" on the line with the echo command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem looks clearly that make is not able to find a command which has been specified in the makefile due to which it throws 127 error. 
Somehow it is not able to find it either in the cygwin bin directory or in the PATH specified.
While updating the cygwin package it could happen that some important utilities are not installed or new versions which have some dependencies are either missed.
 Since the root cause you identified is during paralell processing, better would be to a do a test and passing 
`-O` option to print correct make invocations running in parallel.This option instructs make to save the output from the commands it invokes and print it all once the commands are completed.

```
make -j8 -O
```

Reference link : https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel-Output.html

Would be good to do a small test if you feel echo is really an issue with a simple test code in which I compile files parallely and use `${NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS}` which would take the available processors of the system. You can change it to a specific value if you wish.
 Also I have added .SILENT so I dont require to add @ prefix to all for echo. If you want to debug you can just comment it `#.SILENT` :

```
.SILENT:
.PHONY:compile objs test
TARGET = program.exe
CC=gcc
INC = ./inc
SOURCES = file_1.c file_2.c file_3.c file_4.c file_5.c
OBJ_FILES:= $(SOURCES:.c=.o)


objs: $(OBJ_FILES)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

all: test 

# Enable parallel compilation
compile:
    make -j ${NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS} -O objs

link : compile $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ_FILES) -o $@

test: link 
    # check echo command
    echo "Executing test script"
```

Execute using : make test 
Would be good to test if this works for you or not and if there is something really of an issue in parallel execution or echo command.

**EDIT**:
Would be good to test once with disabling  the Antivirus as also suggested by @matzeri.

Comment: if the problem only arise with make in parallel, it is also possible than an AV is temporaly blocking access to some of the program called by make.  https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda . Can you exclude the AV from scanning the cygwin and the working tree ?

Comment: @matrezi yes you are right but the only way is to disable the software or antivirus or tell the antivirus not to scan utlities coming from cygwin. This cannot be done on cygwin side but on the Antivirus side

Comment: Thank you, @Altaf, I added --output-sync and expected to engage in more troubleshooting. I got one better: everything built correctly. No more errors at all. I retried three times and it built correctly every time. I don't know the root cause, but I have already burned four days on this issue, so I am happy. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it's not make that is failing.  Make is just running whatever commands you provided to it, and those commands are exiting with a non-0 exit code (in this case, 127).  Make has, and can have, *no idea* why your command exited with a non-0 exit code.  All make can do is report the exit code it received.

Adding `-d` won't help because, again, it's not make that's generating the error.  The `-d` option is only useful if something is getting built (or not) in a way you don't expect.  It won't help at all when debugging *recipes*.

Make expects that the command that it invoked will generate sufficient messages, itself, about why it failed that it will allow you to figure it out.  If it doesn't do that then you'll have to fix that: make can't help.

One problem is that prefixing all your recipe command lines with `@` is an anti-pattern.  Telling make to not print anything about what it's doing is like trying to debug your code with a blindfold on.  Don't do that.  If you'd like to have your recipes be hidden most of the time but still be able to show them for debugging purposes, you might try the method described here: http://make.mad-scientist.net/managing-recipe-echoing/

Comment: OK, let me unwrap what you are saying. So if make reports Error 127 for the command `echo "    FILE"`, then the echo command is returning error code 127? That seems to make sense, but it is also somewhat illogical. The echo command returns an error? How does `echo "    file"` return an error?

Comment: Follow-up: I removed all the @ prefixes in the macro. Even so, make still reports errors on lines with echo commands. For example: `make: *** [../../build/rules.mak:398: ../obj/fileN.o] Error 127`, where line 398 is a simple echo command.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I can't explain that, and I especially cannot explain it if it's intermittent and the same recipe runs sometimes and not other times, but it's not a make issue as far as I can tell.  I don't do anything much with Windows and even less with cygwin but all I can suggest is that there's a problem there.  I will say one thing: by convention an exit code of 127 from the shell means "command not found".  Which is definitely odd.

Comment: To be clear it might not be that echo is exiting with 127.  It might be that the shell is exiting with 127 because it couldn't run echo.  I don't know why.  One thing you might consider, just for giggles, is adding a semicolon to the command, so `echo "...";` and see if it still fails that way

Comment: Stupid questions: does `/usr/bin/echo` work ? Is `cygcheck -c` reporting OK for all packages ?

Comment: @matzeri `cygcheck -c` reports everything is OK. Today I even tried wiping out my cygwin and re-installing from scratch. The build still fails with error 127. Not sure what the /usr/bin/echo check would accomplish. The build was failing with error 127 before I added the echo commands. The fact that echo also fails with error 127 indicates some deeper problem: not the cross compiler, not a utility like dos2unix.

Comment: @MadScientist The project is actually using $(V) for the @ prefix management. I translated it to avoid having to explain it. Let me ask this: when using multiple jobs, does make always print an error on the next line after printing the command? I expect the two could be separated by other lines of output, right? So even without the @ prefix, there is no way for me to tell from the output which command generated the error. Right?

Comment: make will first show the command line, then it will invoke a shell and give it the command line to process, then it will wait for the command to complete, then it will examine the exit code of the command and print a message if it was not 0.  If you are running parallel jobs, then everything is exactly the same except instead of waiting for the command to complete make will start more jobs (up to the maximum).  So if you are running multiple jobs their output may be mixed together.

Comment: If you have GNU make 4.0 or better, you can look at the `--output-sync` option... except I don't know if it works on Windows.

Comment: @MadScientist Thank you for the time and effort you put into this answer. The `--output-sync` option solved the problem, as in, everything builds correctly and there are no errors reported. Thanks again!.

Comment: Well, I sure can't explain THAT!  Must be some cygwin weirdness.