# Why can't I run some programs after using unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER)

Tags: c++, linux, linux-namespaces

I'm working on adding some restrictions to my build process - to detect cycles, specifically. To achieve this I've been experimenting with [user namespaces](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unshare.2.html).

Here's my 'hello world' program:

```
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    if( unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER) != 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-e", "-c", "make", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the makefile being run by make, namespace_test.cpp is the name of the file above:

```
namespace_test: namespace_test.cpp
    g++ namespace_test.cpp -o ./namespace_test
```

When everything is up to date (as determined by make) the exec'd program works as expected:

`make: 'namespace_test' is up to date.`

But if `make` actually runs the `g++` invocation I get an opaque error:

```
g++ namespace_test.cpp -o ./namespace_test
make: g++: Invalid argument
make: *** [Makefile:2: namespace_test] Error 127
```

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: I suspect I'm failing to correctly set up the uid_map and gid_map. Will report back an answer if that's the case and I figure it out.

Comment: Is working fine for me in both cases (up to date and after a touch), anyway you have more info about Error 127 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36365752/make-error-127-when-running-trying-to-compile-code)

Comment: Sorry, when you say 'is working fine' do you mean the `namespace_test` program that is invoking its own makefile - or just the makefile?

Comment: I can compile using your `Makefile` and also `touch namespace_test.cpp` and run the program invoking `make`, in both cases it works fine: https://pastebin.com/1402LdRc

Comment: That's interesting, maybe I will compare behavior in other distros. Docker and podman do work on this machine, though, so I think my little test is not totally correct.

Comment: If it helps, thats the ouput of `g++ -v namespace_test.cpp -o namespace_test` on my machine: https://pastebin.com/zDJy4WWS (Ubuntu 21.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was due to my failure to set up the `uid_map` and `gid_map`. I have not produced a satisfactory, explicit, minimal example of the error, but I have written a working minimal solution, that I will share here. Notice that `int main()` is identical, except before `exec`'ing the target command we first set up the `uid_map` and then the `gid_map` (granting ourselves permission via `setgroups`).

On my terminal `$ id` informs me that my real uid and gid are both 1000, so I have hardcoded that in the maps. It is more correct to query for the original id at the start of the process, see this [excellent blog post](http://ifeanyi.co/posts/linux-namespaces-part-2/). Also instrumental in this solution is [this man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/user_namespaces.7.html).

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define fatal_error(...) \
do { \
    fprintf(stderr, "namespace_test \033[1;31merror:\033[0m "); \
    fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__ ); \
    fprintf(stderr, "\n"); \
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
} while(0)

void write_string_to_file(const char* filename, const char* str, size_t str_len)
{
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDWR);
    if(fd == -1)
    {
        fatal_error("Failed to open %s: %m", filename);
    }

    if( write(fd, str, str_len) != str_len )
    {
        fatal_error("Failed to write %s: %m", filename);
    }

    close(fd);
}

void write_uid_mapping()
{
    const char* mapping = "0 1000 1";
    write_string_to_file("/proc/self/uid_map", mapping, strlen(mapping));
}

void write_set_groups()
{
    const char* deny = "deny\n";
    write_string_to_file("/proc/self/setgroups", deny, strlen(deny));
}

void write_gid_mapping()
{
    write_set_groups();

    const char* mapping = "0 1000 1";
    write_string_to_file("/proc/self/gid_map", mapping, strlen(mapping));
}

int main()
{
    if(unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER) != 0)
    {
        fatal_error("Failed to move into new user namespace");
    }

    write_uid_mapping();
    write_gid_mapping();

    execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-e", "-c", "make", NULL);

    return 0;
}
```